# How to stop Redirect and get response in AsyncHttpClient

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, http-get, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a `HTTP GET` which returns status `200` with some response. This response it is given as a result of redirecting.

If I introduce `asyncHttpClient.setEnableRedirects(false);` in my code, then redirection stops and it comes in failure with status 302. But in my application, this status 302 and response associated with it is what I need.

I am searching online and trying to figure out, but I am new to Java so not able to understand how to achieve this.

What I want is, when server returns status 302, I want to trigger onSuccess and capture response. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to stop following redirections with your client and inspect the original response which has the 302 Redirect status code? You might disable redirect handlings when creating the client with the builder.

Comment: Yes, I want to stop redirection with my client and inspect original response which has status code 302. I thought calling setEnableRedirects(false) will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting right what do you need then you could implement your own AsyncHandlers to react with a different AsyncHandler.State for 302 status code. ( https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client#using-custom-asynchandlers) or while creating the client stop to follow redirects like this:

```
asyncHttpClient(config().setFollowRedirect(false))
```

(it might be different from the approach you mentioned above.)

P.S. I'm using 2.5.2 version of the asynchttpclient lib.

Comment: What is config() in this?

Comment: import static org.asynchttpclient.Dsl.config;